# looping json object in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON object containing `{"id":1,"name":"name1"}` which I get from  a rest api and I want to display the name property in a list using ng-repeat.  Below is what I have in my page:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="p in Names">
        {{p.name}}
 </ion-item>
```

It does not display anything with above code and when I change `{{ p.name }}` to `{{ Names }}` it displays `{"id":1,"name":"name1"}`. Iterate and get each properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your JSON object an *array* like this or just an *object*?

```
/* Array - Can ng-repeat on this */
Names = [{"id":1, "name":"name1"}]

/* Object - Cannot ng-repeat on this */
Names = {"id":1, "name":"name1"}
```

If it is just an *object*, `ng-repeat` will not be able to iterate.

You can see an example of this in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNW1uB7QGgVtQzc177TX?p=preview).

---

**Answering question below from user3514822**

In the case of the comment below where `JSON.parse` could return an array of objects or just a single object.

```
var response = { "userlist": [ "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"alex\"}" ] };

$scope.Names=JSON.parse( response.userlist );

if( Object.prototype.toString.call( $scope.Names ) !== '[object Array]' ) {
    $scope.Names = [ $scope.Names ];
}
```

After doing this the `ng-repeat` should work as you have already defined as `$scope.Names` should always be an array.

Comment: Yes you are right, its non array like this $scope.NamesNonArray = {"id": 1, "name": "Foo"}; , How do I deal with it ?

Comment: I have updated my plunker with some explanation to what is happening with each stage. It should also show you how to deal with just an object that is not an array. http://plnkr.co/edit/sNW1uB7QGgVtQzc177TX?p=preview

Comment: The real response data of api is {"userlist":["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"alex\"}"]}, And I might get more users in that list. And I'm parsing it as below, $scope.Names=JSON.parse(response.userlist); And I'm using the Names variable in ng repeat.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
{{Names.name}}
```

you can iterate over an array of objects, but if you have just one object, there's no need.
You would need to iterate if you have something like this:

```
Names = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"}, {"id":2,"name":"name2"}, {"id":3,"name":"name3"}, ...]
```

in this case an ng-repeat="p in Names" would work fine by doing {{p.name}}.

Hope it helps

Comment: If I put {{Names.name}} it displays name twice since it is iterating twice. and object is like this Names={"id":1,"name":"name1"} not the way you have showed in your post.

Comment: you are dealing with a single object therefore there's no need to iterate.

Comment: But in rest api response I get, {"userlist":["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"name1\"}"]} as of now and in future if there are more users, and if there are more users then i'd get {"userlist":["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"name1\"},"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"name2\"}"], In this case it would display only one user name. Am I wrong in parsing response using JSON.parse(response) as per above responses?

Comment: in that case your ng-repeat should be: ng-repeat="user in userlist" then you can do {{user.name}} and/or {{user.id}}. Also I think you should edit your question to reflect the real data you get back from server as it will help to better understand your case :-)

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat is used for lists (repeating things) like:

```
Names = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"}, {"id":2,"name":"name2"}, {"id":3,"name":"name3"}]
```

If you only have **{"id":1,"name":"name1"}** get rid of ng-repeat and simply use **{{Names.name}}**

```
<ion-content ng-controller="testPage">
   <ion-list>                                           
     <ion-item>
            {{Names.name}}
     </ion-item> 
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

If you want to cover both cases just create an array. (when Names is only an object.

```
Names = angular.isObject(Names)?[Names]:Names;
```

Comment: Thanks for response , it works but I might get more names in some cases.

Comment: If you get more Names and it will be an array, than use ng-repeat. If you only return one element you can put it inside a list and then do an ng-repeat on it. I've updated my answer

Comment: The real response data of api is {"userlist":["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"alex\"}"]}, And I might get more users in that list. And I'm parsing it as below, $scope.Names=JSON.parse(response.userlist); And I'm using the Names variable in ng repeat.